# Merge two row records

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables

**Person Table**

```
PersonID   Firstname LastName
1              a         b
2              c         d
3              e         f
4              g         h
5              i         j
```

**Incident Table**

```
InicdentID PersonID 
1             1
1             2
2             3
2             4
3             5
```

I want to STUFF Name with semicolumn for one Incident

```
IncidentID Name 
1            ab;cd
2            ef;gh
3            ij
```

Comment: Do you want to just merge as part of a select statement, or do you want to place the merged rows into a (different) table?

Comment: T-SQL can apply to two different platforms, SQL Server and Sybase/SAP ASE. What product, and which version thereof, are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
create table #person (
PersonID int,
FirstName varchar(5),
LastName varchar(5)
)

create table #incident (  
IncidentID int,
PersonID int
)

insert into #person values (1,'a','b')
insert into #person values (2,'c','d')
insert into #person values (3,'e','f')
insert into #person values (4,'g','h')
insert into #person values (5,'i','j')

insert into #incident values (1,1)
insert into #incident values (1,2)
insert into #incident values (2,3)
insert into #incident values (2,4)
insert into #incident values (3,5)


 select t.IncidentID,
   stuff(
    (select ';' + p.firstname + p.lastname
      from #incident i
      join #person p
        on i.personid = p.personid
      where i.incidentid = t.incidentid
     for xml path('')),
     1,
     1,
     ''
   )
 from #incident t
group by t.IncidentID
```

[Documentation on stuff() command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The actual goodnes in the solution above is the [`for xml path('')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148472/how-for-xml-path-works-when-concatenating-rows) statement.    The `stuff()` (while necessary to answer the question) just removes the redundant semi-colon

Comment: Thanks kevinnwhat I have developed the same but the difference is I was joining on PersonID everytime  "where i.incidentid = t.incidentid". This saved me time. Thanks much